# developing with ASP.NET using framewok

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have been working for 4 years as a PHP developer and I'm currently transferring to ASP.NET (Since I have 4 years of C# experience too, and selected PHP because of specific conditions - now I wish to use my C# knowledge and the .NET Framework is impressive).

When developing with PHP, I always use a framework - or something I've wrote myself (I'm working as a software architect...) or Zend Framework / Yii etc - the reasons is lack of classes, tools and OOP in PHP (such as MVC, ACL, Cache etc.)

When working with ASP.NET MVC 3, I see that combining the MVC framework and the general .NET framework I have many tools, and here is my point: when developing in ASP.NET, do you need to use any other framework than .NET? (just like in PHP I'm using Zend).
If so, there's any recommended frameworks?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

In a .Net world, there are many options infront of you. see below popular vendors;

```
www.devexpress.com
www.telerik.com
www.comonentone.com
www.infragistics.com
```

But most of the time, asp.net is perfect itself. And when you are talking about mvc3. You can use another view engine instead of using Razor(the default one) such as spark. So, i mean that asp.net itself can be expended accroding to your needs.
And when you are working with mvc3, then you have best choice which entity framework. There is alot of support out there for this framework. So good luck in this.

Comment: Just a comment on personally working with infragistics. There support is a little lack luster and i find in general their product isn't quite as powerful as other options.

Comment: i think you are right. But dont look at their control. Just note their hard work they do. you have to still apreciate them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are other frameworks that you can choose to use alongside .NET MVC - but I myself haven't chosen to utilize them in any recent projects. Here are a few examples aside from what others have already pointed out:

- http://www.springframework.net/
- http://sparkviewengine.com/

That said, while I don't personally use frameworks like I mentioned above here in no particular order are a few tools that I have found that I have come to rely on while developing applications within ASP.net MVC:

- [Fluent Nhibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) - If you choose to use Nhibernate as your ORM
- [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) - Dependency Injector
- [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) - object - object mapper
- [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) - error logging facility
- [lg4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) - logging etc

Answer (score 2):

Check out Telerik http://www.telerik.com/ They have some great tools like their RadGrids and specific imput textboxes that once you get used to will save a ton of time and add a lot more flexibility. Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

No THE framework has everything you normally need. But the amount of tooling available is tremendous! We use asp.net 4.0 but we choose DevExpress controlls to get nice look and feel and functionality that would cost too much to build myself.

We worked with almost every component builder in the last 10 years but DevExpress is our favorite for one simple reason. Super fast support! And I agree with the above comment about Infragistics very disapointing support!

But again those vendors or other community frameworks are there too make our life even simpler. By itself THE framework can solve almost everything from THE core libraries.

Good luck switching to C# again my favorite language too!